# QGIS shared project (monitor changes)

Tags: qgis, shared-hosting

I have a software-development background with a powerful use of svn and git.

I work now for a public authority with two offices far from one another. Two other colleagues and I are sharing several QGIS projects and are looking for some features to:

1. Keep track of changes in files
2. Be able to fork/create branches/commit/pull and so on

I think we might do that with git, however this will not track files changes (it will note that the file has changed, but not how as it does for codes and scripts).

What is the most efficient way of managing a shared project and keep track of all the changes with the possibilities to revert files to older versions?

PS: I already checked the suggested questions and many other sources on the net.

Answer (score 2):

Opengis.ch developed [The Trackable QGIS Projects plugin](https://www.opengis.ch/2019/04/09/plugin-for-tracking-qgis-project-files-in-git/) which tracks QGIS project changes.
This plugin allows to save project's file into a stable format (more "readable" in a git repository and easier to track what actually changed).

To track data changes, you could try [geodiff](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/geodiff), a Python library which tracks changes in geospatial data.